# Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт отправлял сгенерированые фразы боту с аккаунта?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт отправлял сгенерированые фразы боту с аккаунта? Т.е. скрипт генерирует какие-то фразы и отправляет их боту с моего аккаунта, или извлекает фразы из txt файла и отправляет боту по одной строке из файла, но при этом не спамил. Нужен только фрагмент отправки боту и библиотека.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если это ваш бот, и вы планируете таким образом автоматизировать какую либо задачу, проще создать чат, в него посадить двух ботов. Они смогут отправлять разную инфу друг другу итд